# Difficulty creating a brand new Eclipse project under version control of existing Git repositories?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am new to Git and having difficulty understanding how (best) to create an Eclipse (Luna) project under Git version control when the repository already exists.

My intuitive thought is that I should:

1.1) Create an empty remote (origin) repository, for example on GitHub.

1.2) Clone the remote repository to my local drive.

1.3) Make Eclipse aware of the connection to my Git repository.

1.4) Create an Eclipse project within the local repository working directory.

1.5) Add and commit the project files to the local repository.

1.6) Push the commit out to the remote (origin) repository.

I think I have a reasonable understanding of how Eclipse interacts with Git after the project already exists, and is already under version control.  But I am starting from the ground up and am having a great deal of confusion getting to that state.

Steps 1.3 & 1.4 are what I can find no documentation for; and have not been able to hack my way through.  I imported a local Git repository into Eclipse using the wizard.  I can then create an Eclipse project in that directory.  But for some reason I am not able to close, or later (e.g. after restarting Eclipse) open the project.  The "Open Project" and "Close Project" options are greyed out on the menu.  The project does not appear in the list of projects for that Eclipse workspace.  I see the external project files that Eclipse has generated.  From within Eclipse, when I try to open the project file, I'm told it is not a project.  If I try again to create the same project, I'm told that it already exists.  So I have a project in the git repository, but can't work with it.  Eclipse doesn't recognize it's a project (for opening) while simultaneously acknowledging that it already exists (preventing redundant creation).  I'm obviously doing this incorrectly.  But have not been successful after many attempts to make this work.

I could follow an alternate order explained at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide:

2.1) Create an Eclipse project completely independent from Git.

2.2) Create a local Git repository around the Eclipse file.

2.3) Create the remote (origin) repository from the local repository.

However, I don't feel comfortable with this approach:

a) If I create things in this order, won't the remote Git repository see the local repository as origin (i.e. it's parent)?

b) I still haven't learned how to create an Eclipse file, from scratch, under version control of a preexisting repository.  I have only learned to create a brand new repository from an existing Eclipse Project.

c) There is discussion in the EGit/User Guide (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) about "Creating a Git Repository for multiple Projects".  This illustrates how to create a brand new repository from several preexisting Eclipse projects.  But it does not explain how to later create a brand new project into the existing repository containing multiple Eclipse projects.

How do I create a brand new Eclipse project, under version control of a preexisting repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the best way to do this:

1) Create a new remote repository.  Use GitHub or

> git init --bare

2) Clone the remote repository to local disk.

> cd pathForTheLocalRepository
>
> git clone remoteRepositoryPath Project1

3) Within Eclipse, File->New->Java Project

3a) In the Create Java Project window, enter project name, uncheck "Use Default Location", and for "Location:" enter or browse to the local repository on disk.
[image: New Java Project window]

4) Eclipse automatically recognizes that it is within a git repository.

5) Right click on the project in the Project Explorer window.

6) Team->Add To Index

7) Team->Commit

8) Team->Push to Upstream

9) The push creates a master branch when we were working with an empty remote repository.